# How do I replace the text of a nested tag in BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, markdown

I'm working on a program that formats HTML for a comment for reddit. So for instance if I have:

```
<i> This is Italics <b> but this is bold and italics</b>  and back to italics <i>
```

I'd want to format it as

```
*This is Italics* ***but this is bold and italics*** *and back to italics*
```

So it would produce:
*This is Italics* ***but this is bold*** *and back to italics*

I'm having trouble finding all  tags inside  tags and replacing them with the right amount of asterisks without messing up the formatting. I've tried several things but the most recent is:

```
italics = soup.find_all('i')
for i in range(len(italics)):
    bold = italics[i].find_all('b')
    for j in bold:
        bold[i].replace_with('***' + bold[i].text + '***')
```

But I get errors when trying to edit nested tags, I don't want to edit every bold tag with ***, just the ones inside the italics so it keeps formatting, the rest I can change to **.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something easier (to understand) like this.

```
italics = soup.find_all('i')
for i in italics:
    print(i.b)
    if i.b:
        i.b.replace_with('***' +i.b.text +'***')

print(soup)
```

And the whole code, stupid but it works

```
italics = soup.find_all('i')
for i in italics:
    print(i.b)
    if i.b:
        i.b.replace_with('* ***'+ i.b.text +'*** *')
    i.replace_with('*'+i.text+ '*')

print(soup)
```